# What is the best method for being able to design a report using SQL 2016?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

When I am trying to edit a report by clicking on the design option, an error message is displayed as:

> The report builder is not available. Please check the report builder URL in report setup.

So is there anything new with reports in SQL 2016 or am I missing something.

I am using SQL Server standard edition - 13.0.15700.28

Comment: Did you install and configure the reporting services correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Himanshu,

SQL Server 2016 stopped this feature. till SQL server 2014 this functionality working name as clickOne Technology.Error"**The report builder is not available. Please check the report builder URL in report setup.**" is the custom error of your code not a part of SQLServer 2016.

So find any other way to open SSRS reports in design view with report builder.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below mentioned URL.Maybe it helps you to open Reportbuilder URL in SQl Server 2016.with the help of WebBrowser  in C#. now we can open Reports builder Successfully.

**URL With Html encoding :-**"reportbuilder:Action=Edit&ItemPath=%2FProject%2FReports%2FRealization&Endpoint=http%3A%2F%2F101.11.11.111%3A80%2FReportServer"

**URL without HTML encoding :-**
"reportbuilder:Action=Edit&ItemPath=Project/Reports/Realization&Endpoint=http//101.11.11.111/ReportServer"
If report builder not install first we need to install in local machine after that it's working.

Thanks ,

Kapil